# emacsformacosx and ImageMagick

Tags: osx

I am attempting to use ImageMagick with emacsformacosx 28.2. I have just installed ImageMagick with `brew`. Evaluating `(image-type-available-p 'imagemagick)` returns `nil`. Much of the advice I have seen centers on *building* emacs with ImageMagic, which is not the case here. I had naively assumed this simply to be a matter of adding something to my .emacs file. What am I missing?

Comment: what are you trying to do with emacs+imagemagick? what's your goal, or why do you need imagemagick?